# How to remove the both top angle from the rectangle in div?

Tags: html

I want to cut out the both top angle from my rectangle to make it look like a house in div tags.

[image: a rectangle that i want]

I tried to use the clip-path but it didn't work. . .

[image: the thing that i made]

```html
<div style="max-width: 620px; height: 200px; background-color: #FFFFFF; ;"></div>
<div style="max-width: 600px; height: 700px; background-color: #ffdbbb; padding: 10px; border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;"></div>
```

Comment: There is no `clip-path` inside your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example does not have a clip path attribute. Just adding it can create a house shape:

```css
clip-path: polygon(0 50%, 50% 0, 100% 50%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
```

You can change the values to tweak the shape and size of the house.

Demonstration:

```html
<div style="max-width: 600px; height: 700px; background-color: #ffdbbb; padding: 10px; clip-path: polygon(0 50%, 50% 0, 100% 50%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);"></div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solution using css border:

```css
.house {
position: relative;
width: 300px; /*assuming the desired width is 300px */
height: 150px;
background-color: #3498db;
}

.roof {
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-left: 150px solid transparent; /* half of the desired width */
border-right: 150px solid transparent; /* half of the desired width */
border-bottom: 100px solid #3498db; /* desired height and color */
}
```

```html
<div class="roof"></div>
<div class="house"></div>
```